# Triangular matrices with conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would like to generate a lower triangular matrix that has checkmarks in the non-zero entries. The way that I created this matrix is the following

```
test1[x_] := ConstantArray["\[Checkmark]", x]
matrix1[x_] := 
 LowerTriangularize[ArrayReshape[test1[x], {x, x}, "\[Checkmark]"]]
```

Now, I wanted to have a different colour for the first column. This I did in the following way:

```
 element = Grid[matrix1[13], Background -> {{Pink}, None}]
```

I can also put a colour in the second column in the following way:

```
element2 = Grid[matrix1[13], Background -> {{Pink, Pink}, None}]
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I put a different value for the zero entries? Example, instead of zero I would like to have an "x". I imagine that this can be done with an `If` command (?) or a `With` but I cannot work around it.
2. How can I put colour in the non-zero elements of the second column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1.

```
matrix1[13] /. 0 -> "x"
```

For 2.

```
colors = Table[{i, 2} -> If[matrix1[13][[i, 2]] == "\[Checkmark]", Pink, None], {i, 13}];
Grid[matrix1[13] /. 0 -> "x", Background -> {None, None, Flatten@colors}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) or [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) to define a function that generates an array with desired dimensions and desired entries below and above the main diagonal:

```
mf1[dims_, a_, b_: 0] := Array[If[# >= #2, a, b] &, dims];

mf1[{13, 13}, "✓", "x"] // Grid
```

[image]

```
mf2[dims_, a_, b_: 0] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> a, dims, b]

mf2[{13, 13}, "✓", "x"] // Grid
```

> same picture

To style selected cells you can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
Grid @ MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Pink] &,  mf1[{13, 13}, "✓", "x"], {2 ;;, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a pity that I cannot accept more than one answer. Thanks for your time and the explanation!